# Allow edit but prevent delete files

Tags: windows, file, permissions, share

I would like to allow my users to modify the specific file/folder but not able to delete it.

I have tried to achieve this using NTFS Permission i.e (Security>Advanced>Edit>Disable Inheritance>Uncheck both Delete permissions).

This does works successfully, meaning that it doesn't allow my users to be able to delete files but parallel to this, it prevents them to edit as well. (MS Word file is used for testing)

When they try to edit file and save it, it prompts them: **Access Denied. Contact your administrator**

Please let me know if someone has solution for this.

**Testing Environment:**

Microsoft Windows 8
Microsoft Windows Server 2008
File: New Word Document

Thank you

Comment: Many programs are written badly in this regard. There's nothing you can easily do about it. Properly, they should truncate an existing file. This would preserve file/security attributes and ACLs. Instead they delete the file and create a new one, which the user may not have the right to do -- precisely because it modifies attributes that the user isn't allowed to modify. I think this is perpetuated legacy behavior and a programmer mindset from the days of FAT, MS-DOS, and Windows 9x. Filesystems work around it with a hack that 'tunnels' certain attributes in this delete/create case.